# Should it suffice to say = is a morphism

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Specifically, I am asking if one can say $\forall X,Y; =:X\times Y\longrightarrow \{\top,\bot\}$? Or can I not say this since there is no set of all sets and therefore no domain for =?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Even if you do write this (for example for $X$ and $Y$ objects of the category of sets), it doesn't respect isomorphisms so it would be pretty much useless in category theory.

Comment: Edited to remove category theory and changed set theory to elementary set theory
I thought asking in category theory would have been appropriate, as it is the study of morphisms

Answer (score 0):

Given a set $X$, it is technically correct to define a map $f : X \times X \rightarrow \{ \text{true}, \text{false} \}$ given by $f(x_1,x_2)= \text{true}$ iff $x_1=x_2$. This is another way of saying that equality is a relation on $X$; the more common way is to consider equality to be $\Delta_X = \{(x,x) : x \in X\} \subseteq X \times X$ (usually a relation from $A$ to $B$ is a subset of their Cartesian product).

However, this only describes equality on a single set. If you want to describe equality between any two sets, you would need to define equality as a relation on the universe, i.e. the collection of all sets. In this sense, equality is not a function (or relation), at least not in a naive set-theoretic way: it's too big.